# Google Web Fonts and other fonts are looking bold and jaggy in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts, bold

I am using "Yanone Kaffeesatz", "Futura", and a couple other fonts on my site. They look great in Chrome Canary, but pretty bad in Firefox...jaggy and oddly bold. So "bold", in fact, that it's making some of the smaller text hard to read. They also display nicely in Safari.

Here's a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yM7c.jpg

I have the font-weights set to "400" (I've also tried "normal") and have "-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased". Both browsers are up-to-date. Nothing seems to help.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: That's very weird indeed; it looks like the text in Firefox has half the resolution of that in Chrome. Do you have a live version we can check out?

Comment: Here's a version on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kBQ2u/

Comment: If it makes any difference, I am running OSX and have a retina display.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it seems that Firefox version simply doesn’t support Retina. Therefore, your problem has nothing to do with the fonts. I don’t know if newer Firefoxes already include support for Retina.

Comment: Does the live version look weird to you? Are you on a PC or Mac?

Comment: Right now I’m using Firefox 18 under Ubuntu Linux on a PC. It looks fine (i.e. non-pixellated) when I zoom in. And as my MacBook doesn’t have a Retina display, I can’t check if that’s the problem.

Comment: @Emily: It seems Firefox 18 has support for Retina: http://www.macrumors.com/2013/01/08/firefox-for-mac-gets-updated-with-retina-support/

Answer (score 0):

Good news! It appears that the problem was due to Firefox 17 not supporting retina displays.

I have since downloaded Firefox 18 (thanks Fitoschido!) and here is an updated view of the text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z99vo.jpg

The text in Firefox still looks a bit thicker, but overall much better! :)